# A bit confused about Candidate Elimination

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

So i encountered an online power point of Candidate elimination algorithm [here](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci367s2c/tutorials/2010.d/Tutorial6.pdf)

And i understand about the first 3 example , but i got my self confused when reading  the fourth example. 
Why after the four example

G = {(?,?,blue,?,?),(Japan,?,?,?,Economy)}

and

not like this for example  G = {(Japan,?,Blue ,?,?),(?,?,?,?,Economy)}

can anyone give me some explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each iteration you need to ask yourself - will my boundary correctly classify my example? if not - how do I change the boundaries so that they are still maximal but will correctly classify the example.

In this case the negative example you get is (USA, Chrysler, Red, Economy) and your boundaries are:

```
G = {(?,?,blue,?,?),(Japan,?,?,?,Economy)}
```

This example doesn't teach you anything in regard to the color "blue", and in fact saying `(Japan,?,Blue ,?,?)`:

1. Is less general than the previous boundary
2. Doesn't help you label the negative example as "negative" (since it is not a blue car!)

On the other hand if you look at the boundary `(?, ?, ?, ?, Economy)` you will see that the negative example does fit it (i.e. miss-classified as positive) so you have to change it! how? by setting the new boundary at `(Japan,?,?,?,Economy)`